# ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text gives other Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, listitem, selectedtext

I have a listbox :

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="genyn">MAS Meeting</asp:ListItem>   
<asp:ListItem Value="smartyn">Smart Meeting</asp:ListItem>  
<asp:ListItem Value="genyn">Project Meeting</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 label1.Text= ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

when I select Project Meeting in the ListBox,  label1 has the text "MAS Meeting". But i want it hav Project Meeting. Is it because I have same value for first and third listitem?

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not do it such a way.

The `value` attribute should be `unique`, otherwise you will get `the first matched item` from the `select`, mean `asp.net List`

```
<asp:ListItem Value="diffValue">Project Meeting</asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I thought there is a way to get text , with same listitem value

Answer (score 1):

You have the same values for `MAS Meeting` and `Project Meeting` - that can cause your problem. Try setting different values for different list items to avoid confusion:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="genyn">MAS Meeting</asp:ListItem>   
    <asp:ListItem Value="smartyn">Smart Meeting</asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem Value="another_genyn">Project Meeting</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I thought there is a way to get text , with same listitem value